# Why my action result data is null when I try console the state using redux and react js

Tags: reactjs, laravel, redux

Hi developers I am currently studying react js with redux for frontend and I want to implement state management (Redux) to my sample project. My Backend I use laravel. Now I already set the Action, Services, Reducers. When I try to console log the props state to my Component it shows that my action data response is null.

Problem: The action data response is null only.

**Here is my MapState & mapDisPatch**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    filterChartRes: state.dashboard.filterChartRes,
  }
}

const mapDisPatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    loadFilterChartData: (selectionRange) => dispatch(loadFilterChartData(selectionRange)),
  }
}
```

My Action:

```
 export const loadFilterChartData = (selectionRange) => {
        return (dispatch) => {
            getFilterChartData(selectionRange).then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
                dispatch({ type: 'FILTER_CHART_RESPONSE', res })
            },
                error => {
                    dispatch({ type: 'FILTER_CHART_ERROR', error });
                }
            )
        }
     }
```

My Services:

```
    export const getFilterChartData = (selectionRange) => {
    const http = new HttpService();
    //let filterData = selectionRange !== "" ? selectionRange : null;
    let url = "auth/filter_chart";
    return http.getData(url)
        .then(data => {
        return data;
    })
}
```

My Reducers:

```
    const initState = {
    filterChartRes: null,
    filterChartErr: null
};


const DashboardReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FILTER_CHART_RESPONSE':
    
            return {
                ...state,
                filterChartRes: action.res.data
            }
        case 'FILTER_CHART_ERROR':
            return {
                ...state,
                filterChartErr: 'action.error'
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}



export default DashboardReducer;
```

My Render:

```
 const {filterChartRes } = this.props

console.log(filterChartRes, "My Filter");
```

My Work Output:

[image: Output]

Back End Controller:

```
public function filter_chart() {
       return 'Sample Data';
    }
```

Hope Someone help on my problem

Comment: `null` is the expected value if you haven't dispatched the action yet or if the action has an error.  Are you calling `loadFilterChartData` in the component?  Check the Redux Dev Tools to see if the error action is getting dispatched instead of a response action.

Comment: @LindaPaiste hi Linda, I solved the problem, I forgot to call the props inside the DidMount. but thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

To solved this issue:

You must call the props inside the DidMount

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    
    this.props.loadFilterChartData()
}
```